# Initialization of references

Tags: c++, reference

I wrote the following code, and I was expecting to get
5
6
6
6, but I got 5 6 5 0 instead. It seems that "val" gets the reference correctly in the beginning, but then it gets lost. Does anybody know where is my mistake?

```
class Count {

    public:  
    void add() {  
    val++;
    }
    void print() {  
    cout << val  << endl;  
    }  
    Count(int c): val(c) {  
    }  
    private:  
    int &val;
};  

int main() {  

    int c = 5;  
    Count teste(c);  
    teste.print();  
    teste.add();  
    teste.print();  
    cout << c << endl;  
    teste.print();  
    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your constructor should take the parameter by reference, not by value.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is you are binding a reference to a parameter passed by value. This should be illegal but maybe it isn't. (Does a parameter passed by value have the same status as a temporary and does that apply to primitive types too?)

What compiler is this?

As SpaceCowboy points out if your constructor takes a reference parameter it will work. It should do, it is the normal way to wrap a reference. Of course val will be invalid once c goes out of scope.

Comment: In the constructor the parameter is an lvalue, so you can bind it to a reference. A nice compiler could warn about the resulting reference being valid for a very short time.

Comment: I compiled it with g++ (I don't know if it makes any difference, but I was running it in a cygwin environment).

Answer (score 0):

You set your private member val as a reference to the *local* variable `c` in your constructor. Once you exit the constructor, its a reference to some random value on your stack.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Either change 'int & val' to 'int val' or change 'Count(int c)' to 'Count(int & c)', that will do the job. by now you're receiving a copy in the c'tor and because you assign that copy to a *reference* you will get undefined behavior because when the flow gets out of the constructor's scope, the copy will be terminated hence your object will hold a reference to a random place on stack!